# FTP backup script authentication error

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I wrote this backup script for testing ftp backup script

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET='192.168.151.139'
NAME='ftpuser'
PASSWD='admin@123'
TIME=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
FILE='root-'$TIME'.tar.gz'
prep=0

echo "Prep values="$prep
echo $FILE

if [ $prep -eq 0 ]
        then
            find /iidb -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -type l -print0 | tar --null --files-from - -cpzvf $FILE
            ftp -n $TARGET <<-EOT
            user $NAME $PASSWD
            put $FILE
            quit
            bye
            EOT
fi
```

The $prep represents a return value from another program executed from within the script necessary to allow the tarring to proceed. Now, when i run the script, it does everything up until the tarring; but when it comes to the ftp connection, I get this error

```
AUTH not understood
AUTH not understood
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
```

Anybody got any idea why this happens?

Comment: I do not believe **KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type** is necessarily an error. Believe that is showing to just remind the user that it will be defaulting to other authentication methods instead of Kerberos (ex. plaintext).

Comment: Yes, agree with above. Did you confirm if the file gets transferred or not? Maybe you need to redirect `std-err` to a separate file (if you're lucky enough to have an `ftp` client that writes to std-err) and build a step to look for "real" errors in that tmp_err file. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, right, should have thought of checking if the file did transfer. And to answer that question, yes it did. Thanks for the explanation of why i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the script executed fine, it was just bad assumption on my part that the file transfer failed due to the authentication type rejection.